# Error: PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL

Tags: oracle11g

I am getting the below error message. Can you please help me to sort out this problem.

"Error: PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL"

This is my coding.

```
  create or replace procedure inst4 is
  var1 varchar2(20);
  type nest is table of coll%rowtype;
  emp1 nest;
  cursor emp2 is select * from coll;
  ex_dml_errors exception;
  l_error_count  NUMBER;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_dml_errors, -24381);
  begin 
  select * BULK COLLECT into emp1 from coll;
  FORALL  i in emp1.FIRST..EMP1.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
  insert into coll values ('Shan',50000);
  insert into coll values('Yan',70000);
  insert into coll values('than',null);
  insert into coll values('unibi',9000);
  exception 
  WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
  l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
   FOR i IN 1 .. l_error_count LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || i || 
      ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ||
      ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
   END LOOP;
  END;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Only the first insert is part of the `forall`, and it doesn't use `emp1` - hence the error. Are you really trying to create four identical  new records for every existing record in `coll`?

Comment: I want to insert four different records consecutively and it shouldn't stop if one insert contains error or null...Can you please suggest me

Comment: What is the connection betweenthe four new records and those you selected into `emp1`? There doesn't seem to be any, so `forall` doesn't seem to be what you want. You could do each insert in its own block, or use an error logging table. Similar questions were asked yesterday, but you seem to have misinterpreted one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first `insert` is part of the `forall`, and it doesn't use a row from the `emp1` collection - hence the error.

Based partly on a later question, it looks like you're trying to populate a collection with four sets of values and then use that to perform a bulk insert; so nothing to do with the collection you're currently populating from the bulk select:

```
create table maav (id varchar2(10), sal number not null);

create or replace procedure bulk_ins is
  type t_maav_rows is table of maav%rowtype;
  l_maav_rows t_maav_rows;
  l_error_count  number;
  ex_dml_errors exception;
  pragma exception_init(ex_dml_errors, -24381);
begin
  l_maav_rows := t_maav_rows();
  l_maav_rows.extend(4);
  l_maav_rows(1).id := 'Shan';
  l_maav_rows(1).sal := 50000;
  l_maav_rows(2).id := 'Yan';
  l_maav_rows(2).sal := 70000;
  l_maav_rows(3).id := 'than';
  l_maav_rows(3).sal := null;
  l_maav_rows(4).id := 'unibi';
  l_maav_rows(4).sal := 9000;

  forall i in l_maav_rows.first..l_maav_rows.last save exceptions
    insert into maav values l_maav_rows(i);
  exception 
    when ex_dml_errors then
      l_error_count := sql%bulk_exceptions.count;
      dbms_output.put_line('Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
      for i in 1 .. l_error_count loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Error: ' || i || 
          ' Array Index: ' || sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index ||
          ' Message: ' || sqlerrm(-sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_code));
      end loop;
end;
/
```

Then when that is executed:

```
exec bulk_ins;

anonymous block completed
Number of failures: 1
Error: 1 Array Index: 3 Message: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ()

select * from maav;

ID                SAL
---------- ----------
Shan            50000 
Yan             70000 
unibi            9000
```

Another way is to do each insert individually, which is less efficient, and to wrap each in its own block with an exception handler:

```
create or replace procedure bulk_ins is
  null_ex exception;
  pragma exception_init (null_ex, -1400);
begin
  for r in (
    select 'Shan' as id, 50000 as sal from dual
    union all select 'Yan', 70000 from dual
    union all select 'than', null from dual
    union all select 'ubini', 9000 from dual
  )
  loop
    begin
      insert into maav (id, sal) values (r.id, r.sal);
    exception
      when null_ex then
        dbms_output.put_line('Error: ' || sqlerrm);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Then when the procedure is executed the same three records are inserted, and the output is:

```
anonymous block completed
Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."MAAV"."SAL")
```

You could also use [the built-in error logging mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55097) which would mean you didn't need to use any PL/SQL; but would also mean you have to be able to create the error logging table.

If you're controlling the data you're trying to insert I'm not really sure why you'd even attempt to insert a value you know isn't valid.

Comment: Awesome Alex. You are great. Many thanks for your help. Is this the only way to insert the records? or do you have any other ways without collection?

Comment: As zaratustra asked, where are the values you're using coming from? You could do four individual inserts with their own exception handlers. But either way this implies the values are being hard-coded.

Comment: Hi Alex,  Am inserting on my own. This is what the requirement is. Thanks